# Postgres extra data after last expected column CSV

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv, copy

I have a CSV like this

```
something,other,5,"The problem, is "right" here"
```

to import I write

```
COPY table_name FROM '/tmp/data.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

now, I think that the problem is the double quote inside the doble quote, am I right?
So, how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add some real data, your table DDL and what is exactly the error message ?

Answer (score 0):

If you ever have doubt, you can just put the data directly into a table and then export the contents using the same copy command (only do "copy to").  Or, you can put it in the spreadsheet of your choice and export to CSV.

```
something,other,5,"The problem is ""right"" here"
```